# ng build --prod fails when I tried importing a javascript file in app-module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, aot, ng-build

I have to import a javascript file in my app module

`import { OtherComponent } from './node_modules/blahblah/OtherComponent.js'`

Notice that this OtherComponent is a javascript file already.

Then inside my @NgModule, I added this component to my declaration.

When I run "ng build --prod", it gives me error:

> ERROR Unexpected value 'OtherComponent' declared by the module
> 'AppModule'
>
> Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Is there a way to fix this? when I don't have access to the ts file of OtherComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You should not import JS files like this.

Inside the angular-cli.json file.

> "scripts": [
>       "./node_modules/blahblah/OtherComponent.js"   ];

Then restart your project. This should do the job.

Comment: ok. This OtherComponent has to declared in the appmodule though, so that I can use it throughout my app. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok. for that, add this in typings.d.ts

declare var OtherComponent:any;
Import it in your file as

import * as otherComponent from 'OtherComponent';

Comment: still no luck. When I import * as otherComponent from 'OtherComponent', 'OtherComponent' is not recognized